# Good project management cheat sheet

Tags: tools

I see various ones on the web (such at [this one](http://www.eljamal.com/pm/docs/Cheat%20Sheet.pdf)), but not being a project manager, I can't really tell which ones are good. I'm looking for a checklist of things to do and important terms; specifically for someone who is new at project management.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure it's clear what is being asked here.  Can you please edit your question and add more information, such as the **specific problem that you are facing** and what you're looking for.  I'm not sure this is a great question in it's current format as it's pretty vague.  I'm tempted to close it as `not a real question`, but I think the question could be improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one I carry around with me all the time: [The Project Breathalyzer](http://www.niwotridge.com/PDFs/Project%20Breathalyzer.pdf).

So I beg to disagree that it is only useful for a beginner :-). When you're tied up in project work, it is a healthy habit to sit back at a quiet moment and reflect upon your project. A good checklist can help organise your thoughts.

I found the Breathalyzer through [Glen Alleman](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/)'s site, which is a treasure trove for beginners and experts. One blogpost from Glen is of particular interest for your question: [A simple way to put PMBOK to work.](http://herdingcats.typepad.com/my_weblog/2008/05/a-simple-way-to-put-pmbok-to-work.html)

What I also found useful over the years is a copy of *Table 3-1. Project Management Process Groups and Knowledge Areas Mapping* in the PMBOK. (currently on page 43 in the Fourth Edition).

Update

I actually forgot to mention the most important one, which is my own checklist. It is based upon the Breathalyzer, the PM methodology of the organisation I work for and personal experience. I strongly advise you to start creating **your own checklist** today (styarting with the examples provided here). It will be a good friend along the way.

Comment: +1 on Alleman!  Call it a cheat sheet or checklist, it is an advisable practice.

Comment: IMO, a "checklist" sounds mutch better than a cheat cheat, and I also advise one, and it should grow/evolve.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not so fond of cheat sheets, as I don't trust in recipes and prefer real thinking. But it can be a good help for a beginner, I think.

The official Project Management for Dummies cheat sheet should be a good beginning, especially if you're not familiar with project management:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/project-management-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html

Some other cheat sheets:

http://www.thepracticalpm.com/serendipity/index.php?/archives/18-PM-Cheat-Sheet.html
Its step-by-step approach seems interesting and make it immediatly usable for a project.

http://www.focus.com/fyi/human-resources/managers-cheat-sheet-101-common-sense-rules-leaders/
This one has a more transverse approach, things you should know or you should think about all the time, even if I'm not ok with all the points: Is body language really so important for a PM? I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fond of checklists myself. I think they lead to sloppy thinking. Better understanding the process can lead to using the right tools at the right time. If it's a memory aid for a new methodology, I like it to be a list of questions and prompts. (@david, a checklist is a list of points that need to be checked off. Anything that makes someone think, isn't a checklist). 
For instance.

**Do you think you've completed initiation? Can you answer the following.**

Do you know what you are supposed to be delivering - could you explain it in less than a minute?
Who are your key stakeholders and why are they key?
When is your planning session? Who will be there and why?

I hope that illustrates the idea.

Comment: Pilots and astronauts have used checklists for years.  The concept of checklists has most recently been adopted by physicians and surgical suites doing surgery.  The outcomes are measurably exhibited.  A checklist is both something that is merely checked off as well as something about which you need to think/analyze.  I use one in my verysimpletofly airplane; would not think about leaving earth without it.  The efficacy is simply not debatable.